# tag next to a label in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

I do not have the luxury of using jQuery, I want to hide the span tag in certain conditions using Javascript and the span tag does not have an id.

```
"<label name="lcity" id="lcity" for="city" class="formLabel" title="City">City:</label>
<span class=spanclass>*</span>
```

I tried something like this and did not work:

```
var countyFieldLabel = document.getElementById('lcity').nextElementSibling;
countyFieldLabel.visibility="hidden";
```

Can anyone suggest something please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost go it right:-

`Visibility` is not an element attribute instead it is a style attribute.

use

```
 countyFieldLabel.style.visibility="hidden";
```

Instead of

```
countyFieldLabel.visibility="hidden";
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/B7WjJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use nextSibling instead of nextElementSibling:

```
function hideSpan()
{
     var element = document.getElementById("lcity").nextSibling.style.visibility = 'hidden';      
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="hideSpan()">     
    <label id="lcity" for="city" class="formLabel" title="City">City:</label><span class=spanclass>*</span>       
</body>
```

In Addition, please remove your name attribute in label. It is not allowed.